# Android memoryInfo values

Tags: android, memory-management

I am using this block of code for determing, actual allocated memory.

```
    ActivityManager activityManager =  (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new MemoryInfo();
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
    long one=memoryInfo.availMem;
    Log.i("memory free1", "" + memoryInfo.availMem);
```

While creating and asigning String[100] field, I get value 61440. Is it in bytes or kB? Documentation says nothing about it.

Thanks

Comment: `getMemoryInfo` give memory in bytes

Comment: getMemoryInfo is void, it cannot be accessed to give memory in bytes

Answer (score 2):

`ActivityManager.MemoryInfo`:
`availMem`, `totalMem`, `threshold` are all in bytes.